# Domain field many2one based on another many2one field Odoo 11

Tags: odoo-11

hello everyone I am odoo newbies I have created a module to Modify the Accounting module. I want to modify vendor bills and customer invoices and ai have added a new column called Budget to fetch all the budget it's a many2one field I want when I select a budget to show me only the analytic account related to it.

```
class custom_accounting_edit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crossovered.budget.lines'

    analytic_account_id = fields.Many2one('account.analytic.account', 'Budget line')


class BillsEdit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice.line'

    budget_id = fields.Many2one('crossovered.budget', string='Budget')
    account_analytic_id = fields.Many2one('account.analytic.account',
                                          string='Budget line')

    @api.onchange('budget_id')
    def onchange_analytic_account_id(self):
        for rec in self:
            return {'domain': {'analytic_account_id': [('analytic_account_id', '=', rec.budget_id.id)]}}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVYjc.png)

Comment: What is the field name referencing `account.invoice.line` from `crossovered.budget`?

Comment: you mean this account_analytic_id = fields.Many2one('account.analytic.account',
                                          string='Budget line')

Comment: No, maybe x2many field defined in `crossovered.budget` model.

Comment: this what I found on crossovered.budget  "crossovered_budget_line = fields.One2many('crossovered.budget.lines', 'crossovered_budget_id', 'Budget Lines',
        states={'done': [('readonly', True)]}, copy=True)"

Comment: and crossovered_budget_id is a field in crossovered.budget.lines

Comment: I added an answer below according to your configuration, check it and let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: thanks a lot, pal you saved my day it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The method is invoked on a pseudo-record that contains the values present in the form, so you do not need to loop over `self`.

You need to use `id` field in the domain to filter accounts using the value of budget lines analytic account (It will return the `id` field value).

You can use `mapped` which will return the union of all budgets analytic accounts, with duplicates removed.

```py
@api.onchange('budget_id')
def onchange_analytic_account_id(self):
    return {'domain': {'account_analytic_id': [
        ('id',
         'in',
         self.mapped('budget_id.crossovered_budget_line.analytic_account_id.id')
         )]
    }
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, pal you saved my day it works like a charm.

Comment: Hello pal I need your help. I have a custom accounting module inherits from odoo accounting module. I have created a budget and a budget has someone responsible for, and an analytic account related to this budget. I want to create vendor bills and customer invoices based on an analytic account related to the specific budget and I want to send an email notification message to the person responsible for the budget in his email when I create a new bill or invoice to notify him that with a message ( a new bill has been created you need to validate it).

Comment: So you need to automatically email the responsible when an invoice is created?

Comment: exactly invoice or bill

Comment: I answered your question at [How to send mail automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66098754/how-to-send-mail-automatically-while-creating-new-vendor-bill-or-customer-invoic/66104992#66104992).

Comment: I am sorry to bother you but I really need your help I am a trainee.  my mentor asks me to move the budget_id field from account.invoice.line model to account.invoice model and in the view after date_due in vendor bills and when I select a budget should fetch only the analytic account that related to in Bill section, please help me.

Comment: Do you need to move the budget to the parent model and keep the `account_analytic_id` in the invoice lines?

Comment: exactly that what I want

Comment: Did you create another question? I think you should because you have a new requirement or at least edit your question and I will try to answer it.

Comment: I did but no one reply and this the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66207455/show-only-analytic-account-related-to-specific-budget-in-vendor-bills-odoo-11-in

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@api.onchange('budget_id')
def onchange_analytic_account_id(self):
    account_ids = [line.analytic_account_id.id for line in self.budget_id.crossovered_budget_line]
    return {'domain': {'analytic_account_id': [('id', 'in', account_ids)]}}
```

Comment: gave this error " raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)
ValueError: Expected singleton: crossovered.budget.lines(6, 7)"