# How to send mail automatically while creating new vendor bill or customer invoice in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Hello everyone I have a custom accounting module inherits from odoo accounting module. I have created a budget and a budget has someone responsible for, and an analytic account related to this budget. I want to create vendor bills and customer invoices based on an analytic account related to the specific budget and I want to send an email notification message to the person responsible for the budget in his email when I create a new bill or invoice to notify him that with a message ( new bill has been created you need to validate it).

Answer (score 1):

You can use automated actions:

1. Configure the outgoing email server.
2. Set the email of the related partner to the user who creates the invoice and the same for the responsible.
3. Install the `base_automation` module.
4. Create an automated action which will trigger the invoice creation:
   Go to `Technical / Automation / Automated Actions` and create new action.

   *For example:*

   - **name**: `Email responsible`
   - **Model**: `Invoice`
   - **Action To Do**: `Send email`
   - **Email Template**: `Invoicing: Invoice email`
   - **Trigger Condition**: `On Creation`

You may duplicate the `Invoice email` template and change the `To (Partners)` to the responsible.