# show only analytic account related to specific budget in vendor bills odoo 11 Invoicing custom module

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Hello everyone  I have added a new field to `account.invoice` and add that field to the vendor bills view to fetch all budget. After a specific budget selected I want to show only analytic account related to this budget in the Bill section using onchange.

Here is account.invoice [image]

```py
class custom_accounting_invoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    creating_user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Project Manager', default=lambda self: self.env.user)
    email = fields.Char('Email', related='creating_user_id.login')
    budget_id = fields.Many2one('crossovered.budget', string='Budget')


    @api.onchange('budget_id')
    def onchange_analytic_account_budget(self):
        return {'domain': {'invoice_line_ids.account_analytic_id': [
            ('id',
             'in',
             self.mapped('budget_id.crossovered_budget_line.analytic_account_id.id')
             )]
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override an existing onchange method in invoice lines to change the `analytic_account_id` domain.

In the following example the domain is set when the `Unit of Measure` change and only if the `budget_id` field is set:

```py
class BillsEdit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice.line'

    account_analytic_id = fields.Many2one('account.analytic.account',
                                          string='Budget line')

    @api.onchange('uom_id')
    def _onchange_uom_id(self):
        res = super(BillsEdit, self)._onchange_uom_id()
        account_ids = self.mapped('invoice_id.budget_id.crossovered_budget_line.analytic_account_id.id')
        new_domain = {}
        if account_ids:
            new_domain['account_analytic_id'] = [('id', 'in', account_ids)]
            if 'domain' in res:
                res['domain'].update(new_domain)
            else:
                res['domain'] = new_domain
        return res
```

Comment: thank you very very much for saving my day

Comment: what can I do for you?